# Criteria for the sum of two middle values in a linear ordering to be a maximum?

Tags: real-numbers, order-theory, maxima-minima

Consider two sets of real numbers $\{a,b,c\}, \{d,e,f\}$ with some linear ordering. I am interested in trying to understand the behaviour of the sum of the middle values of each linear ordering

1. It is known that if $a<b<c$ and $d<e<f$, then $b+e$ stays in the middle in the new ordering $a+d<b+e<c+f$
2. It is also known that if $a<b<c$ and $d>e>f$, then 3 possibilities can happen:

a. The two orderings are complementary, thus $k=a+d=c+f$. Then the max and min of the parent orderings are evened out, leaving behind $b+e$ which can be max or min or equality depending on whether $b+e<k,b+e>k,b+e=k$

b. The magnitudes involved in the ordering $a<b<c$ is not large enough to complement $d<e<f$ thus $a+d<b+e<c+f$ results

c. The magnitudes involved in the ordering $d>e>f$ is not larger enough to complement $a<b<c$ thus $a+d>b+e>c+f$ results

But what about the general case where the two orderings are formed by all permutations of symbols $d,e,f,<,>$ and $a,b,c,<,>$ respectively, such as $a < b < c$ and $d < f < e$, what condition is needed to ensure $b+e$ is a maximum?

Comment: What do you mean by "linear" in linear ordering. And is $d<f<e$ the correct generalisation?

Comment: Linear as in the definition in order theory where there are no incomparable elements and they follow trichotonmy. As for d < f < e, I am thinking about all permutations of d,e,f as well the <,>. I will make that clearer in the edit